# Framework for cross platform desktop apps

Tags: desktop-application

I am looking for a good framework to code a cross-platform app in that would be able to run on Windows, Mac OS and Linux.

There are a few things that I want:

- Stability: The desktop app must be stable and low response and loading times.
- Simple to make responsive layouts and style it to my liking.
- Look exactly the same on every operating system.
- Only require one installer and not anything preinstalled on the users computer.

I have used QT before but I don't really like how the UI development works. It is very difficult to create custom styles.

I know it is a lot to ask for but what do you suggest ;)

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try [ELECTRON](https://electronjs.org) ?

> If you can build a website, you can build a desktop app. Electron is a framework for creating native applications with web technologies like JavaScript, HTML, and CSS. It takes care of the hard parts so you can focus on the core of your application.

PS: [Skype](https://www.skype.com) and [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com) are built using Electron.

Comment: Can I do complex conversations between binary files using electron? Will it run stable?

Comment: You can do almost everything with electron but take care of your resources, do optimizations as more as possible

Comment: If this answer was any helpful to you, mark it as the correct one

Comment: I hear that apple's app store rejects apps made with electron since it makes certain API calls internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can go with the `Flutter 2.0` application (together with `Dart`).

It's not only compatible with [Windows, Linux, macOS,](https://flutter.dev/desktop) but also Android, iOS, web.

Read more about `Flutter` [here](https://flutter.dev).

---

P.S Desktop support is still in `beta`, but it's already in the official release, so it's mostly stable.